# I can't parse the site, Python Selenium

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I have one problem with which I don’t know how to cope for 2 days, I’m not sure that it can be solved somehow. Maybe there is someone more experienced here who will tell you how to solve the problem, or at least in what direction to go.
I need to write a parser for allegro.pl, there are 2000 product links that need to be checked for availability. Only here there is some very strong protection, I do it through selenium, I connected a proxy, but after 1-2 iterations the site blocks the IP or asks for a captcha, but then everything blocks exactly.
Outlined the main functions in the code

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import exel
import zipfile
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth

LINK_IMG_ERROR = 'https://assets.allegrostatic.com/metrum/icon/stop-sign-92284fffce.svg'
PROXY_HOST = ''
PROXY_PORT = 8000  # Your proxy port
PROXY_USER = ''
PROXY_PASS = ''

NORMAL_STATUS_CODE = 200
headers = ({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Accepts': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
})

manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"76.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
let config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
        },
        bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});
function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)


def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, headers=None):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        plugin_file = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(plugin_file, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr('manifest.json', manifest_json)
            zp.writestr('background.js', background_js)

        options.add_extension(plugin_file)

    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={headers}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)

    stealth(
        driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win64",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
    )
    return driver


def check_stock_selenium(driver, url_list):
    list_link_error = []
    try:
        for url in url_list:
            driver.get(url=url)
            time.sleep(3)
            html = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            stock_info = soup.find_all('img', {"class": "meqh_en msa3_z4 mhd5_0m ivrkk m0s5_fg m0t1_7i mse2_56 mg9e_0 mj7a_0 mh36_0 mvrt_16 mvrt_24_l mpof_z0 mjyo_lo"})

            if len(stock_info) > 0 and stock_info[0].get_attribute_list('src') == LINK_IMG_ERROR:
                list_link_error.append(url)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
    if len(list_link_error) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    driver = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True, headers='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
    result = check_stock_selenium(driver, exel.get_data('my_spreadsheet.xlsx'))
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already telling me the problem.

As far as I understand: The site you are trying to scrape, checks the number of requests from a user and blocks if it meets a certain threshold.

What you can do is something like this:

- Create a background job to collect web proxies into a database. Use proxy listing sites to collect them.
- The quality of the proxies in general will be low. Any proxy you tried to connect X times and failed, should be marked as usesless/disabled.
- Use the proxies from database to connect to the site. If it is blocked after a threshold switch to next proxy.
- Give positive scores to the proxies that can connect to the site.

I did this before for scraping protected sites. And it worked.

Search web for: **"free https proxies list"**

This is an example site (I did not check the quality)
https://proxyscrape.com/free-proxy-list

As I said most of the free proxies will be low quality or useless.
So you need to have your quality checks and a job thread which is running in the background to find more proxy listings.

I hope this helps.